# too many connections for role dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

How to delete all connections (because of the mistake  too many connections for role)?
how to do it in dbeaver?

Tried

1. close all active scripts
2. pg_stat_activity - does not start

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
from pg_stat_activity 
where usename = 'x'
```

2. database - close all connections also does not give results.
3. max connections -10

Comment: This looks like fragments of internal dialog.  Please edit this so that it makes sense to someone not already inside your head.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem the system gets error "too many connections for the role". And i can t close these connections, so i can t work. I tried several variants but they don t work. I need to close all connections.